# c++ how to loop code in a different way?(not the kind you think)

Tags: c++

Ok, so I'm trying to make a VERY simple text roleplay game and I'm having a problem. I don't know what kind of loop I could use to loop this code:

```
getline(cin, response);
if(response == "Pick up the gun")
{
    cout << "You pick up the gun.\n";
    cout << "Knock down the door with it? (Y/N)\n";
    getline(cin, response);
    if(response == "Y")
    {
        cout << "The door opens.\n";
        cout << "You see a zombie.\n";
        cout << "You see an open window.\n";
        cout << "What do you do?\n";
        getline(cin, response);
        if(response == "Shoot the zombie")
        {
            cout << "The zombie dies and it attracts other zombies.\n";
            cout << "GAME OVER!\n";
            cin.get();
            return 0;
        }
        else if(response == "Jump out the window")
        {
            cout << "The zombie does not hear you and you safely make it out!\n";
            cout << "VICTORY!\n";
            cin.get();
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else if(response == "N")
    {
    }
}
else if(response == "Open the door")
{
    cout << "It appears to be locked.\n";
}
```

So if they get it wrong(for example, they choose 'open the door' it will just say its locked and it will END THE PROGRAM for some reason. I WANT it the user to be able to choose a different choice, not have it just be blank or broken or end etc.)it would just loop, but when i try it either doesent end the program and just makes it weher i can type and nothing happens no matter what, or it absoulutley SPAMS the text like 100 times and i can't do anything etc. its very strange. so how could I do that? thx!

Comment: It seems that 90% of the code isn't related to the problem, please narrow it down.

Comment: Maybe redesign it like a *state machine*. Then you only change the state if the command is recognised.

Comment: We only see some if statements how are we supposed to know the reason for your program leaving the loop if you don't show us the loop?

Comment: @KerrekSB Agreed. For-switch loops have limited use. This is one of the uses.

Comment: i don't use a loop at the moment. I need to figure out which kind of loop I need to use to JUST loop that code without spamming or strange glitches.

Comment: **while** loop seems better suited for me in this example. While (input!="Y" || input!="N" || *whatever else you want as an acceptable input*)
then print the lane you want.

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing a lot of this, I suggest you make it easy for the reader...  Kind of a pick-a-path thing rather than the user having no idea what they're supposed to type.

```
int GetChoice( vector<string> & choices )
{
    cout << "Do you wish to:" << endl;

    // Output choices 1..N
    for( int i = 0; i < choices.size(); i++ ) {
        cout << "  " << i+1 << ". " << choices[i] << endl;
    }

    // Ask user for their choice.
    for(;;) {
        // This is pretty basic.  You could use getline instead...
        cout << "Enter your choice: ";
        cout.flush();
        int n;
        cin >> n;

        if( n < 1 || n > choices.size() ) {
            cout << "Invalid choice.\n";
            continue;
        }

        // Output the choice and clear the choices vector (so it can be used again)
        cout << "You " << choices[n-1] << endl;
        choices.clear();
        return n;
    }
 }
```

Then:

```
 vector<string> opts;
 int choice;

 cout << "You see a door and a gun.\n";
 do {
     opts.push_back( "try the door" );
     opts.push_back( "pick up the gun" );
     choice = GetChoice(opts);
     if( choice == 1 ) cout << "The door appears to be locked.\n";
 } while( choice == 1 );
 if( choice != 2 ) GameQuit();

 cout << "You are armed and dangerous.  Now what?\n";
 opts.push_back( "assault the door with the gun" );
 opts.push_back( "look down the barrel and pull the trigger" );
 choice = GetChoice(opts);

 if( choice == 1 ) {
    cout << "The door crashes from its hinges.\n";
    cout << "You see a zombie and an open window.\n";
    opts.push_back( "shoot the zombie" );
    opts.push_back( "jump out the window" );
    choice = GetChoice(opts);

    if( choice == 1 ) {
        cout << "The zombie explodes and it attracts hundreds more zombies.\n";
        GameOver();
    } else if( choice == 2 ) {
        cout << "You plummet 17 stories to a grisly death.\n";
        GameOver();
    } else {
        GameQuit();
    }
 } else if( choice == 2 ) {
    cout << "Your head explodes.\n";
    GameOver();
 } else {
    GameQuit();
 }
```

Not saying it's pretty, but this format allows you to have other options available at all times (such as 'q' to quit, which returns zero maybe).

Obviously you'll see that doing the game in this fashion is going to cause lots of nested `if`-blocks...  It would be better to arrange the game as a state machine, as previously suggested in comments.  Ultimately, you could define a simple text-file containing the entire game.

Answer (score 0):

Create a boolean variable preset to FALSE.
If the user chooses "Jump out the window" change the boolean variable to TRUE.
Then put the entirity of your code in a loop.

```
while (myBooleanVariable == FALSE) {

  //insert game code

}
```

Comment: when it gets to the Y/N do you want to knock down the door part if I type N and then Y it won't proceed or do any text at all.

Comment: Strangely, I did nothing and it worked a few minutes ago but when I try now and type 'Open the door' it just ends the proccess. Why? Code has had no modifications.